# CO2 pressure regulator for keg

Tags: sensors

Is there anything like the link below that I can read/set with an arduino/raspberry pi?

I'd like to be able to control this completely from a computer in my kegerator setup.

Any search terms that might help me find something would be useful too.

Thanks

[http://www.amazon.com/Taprite-Product-Pressure-Kegerator-Regulator/dp/B0060NOX40/ref=lh_ni_t?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=AEUC6GAA8XY7Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0060NOX40)

Comment: A good search term is [pressure transducer](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=arduino+pressure+transducer).

Comment: I also need to be able to adjust the delivery pressure to the kegs though - not just measure the pressure

Comment: If it's to be cheaper, I'd be surprised if you ended up with something that costs less than some mechanical stuff. If it's for automation, you're going to have a struggle finding a pneumatic regulator that works with Arduino... you might have to use a motor to turn a dial...

Comment: For adjusting pressure, search for a [solenoid valve](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=solenoid+valve). Just make sure that whatever you get is food grade and can handle enough gas pressure (same goes for the transducer).